# How to insert and append a json array into a column in SQL

Tags: sql, json

I've followed a few tuts online and I've come across a simple approach but its throwing some errors.

I have 2 columns in my table.

- user_id (INT)
- purchased_products (JSON)

I simply want to keep an array of purchased product IDs in the purchased_products column in json format ["32","33","86","10"].

My query, looking to append 34 onto the array:

```
UPDATE customers_purchased_products 
SET 
purchased_products = JSON_MODIFY(purchased_products,
        'append $.purchased_products',
        '34')
WHERE
user_id = 12345
```

Is this valid SQL?

Im also getting an error:
`Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION database_name.JSON_MODIFY does not exist`

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Google cloud Mysql.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Have a look at the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have managed to get somewhere since then. I will update my question with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

So i ended up simply needing to insert the first instance as just json formatted text. The remaining products could be added to the newly created array using a different function.

```
-- Insert a new row into the purchased products table
INSERT INTO purchased_products (
    user_id, -- INT
    purchased_products -- JSON
)

-- 1) The user ID (primary key)
-- 2) Formatted json array with the first purchased product ID
VALUES ( 12345, '["35"]' )

-- If the user id already exists, append the existing array with the product ID
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 

    -- JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(existing purchases array, index, product_id)
    purchased_products = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(purchased_products, '$[0]', "35")
```

Whilst there may be multiple items per order, a single statement for each item will cover every instance.